# Why UILabel giving extra padding in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I am using `UILabels` in `UITableViewCell`
My code is below, I don't know why it gives the padding ?

```
  cell.lbl1.text = "Name            - " 
  cell.lbl2.text = "Class           - " 
  cell.lbl3.text = "Reason          - "
```

[image]

I am looking for consistent spacing from text before `"-"`

Comment: You are assuming each character is equally wide. That is only true for monospace fonts. What is this UI supposed to do? How about putting the `-` character into another label? And put both labels into a `UIStackView`? A horizontal stack view, with `.fillEqually` distribution?

Comment: @Sweeper making Stack with two label makes fatty UI. Any way to achieve using single `UILabel` ?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks I used `Menlo`font & it works. I am wondering if we can achieve with system font? Any workAround ?

Comment: No workarounds. If the font is not monospace, it can't be used to achieve whitespace of the equal distance. With non-monospace fonts the only option is to use two labels and configure space between them with layout. I would reconsider your statement about "fatty UI." A couple more labels for modern devices is nothing: You should only optimize when performance is measured and its drop is proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming each character is equally wide. That is only true for monospace fonts. You can get the default monospaced font by using `UIFont.monospacedSystemFont`:

```
cell.lbl1.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: .regular)
```

If you don't want to change the font, a simple solution would be to put the "-" character into another `UILabel`. This way, you can constraint all the labels on the left to have the same width, and that the "-" labels would be on the right of them.

An example of doing this with `UIStackView`s:

```
func makeLabel(_ text: String) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = text
    label.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: .regular)
    return label
}

func makeHStack(_ text: String) -> UIStackView {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [makeLabel(text), makeLabel("-")])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // freely adjust this 0.4 ratio
        stackView.arrangedSubviews[0].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4)
        // making the width equal to a constant is also an option
    ])
    return stackView
}

// constructing the 3 rows and placing them into a superview
let vstack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [makeHStack("Name"), makeHStack("Class"), makeHStack("Reason")])
vstack.axis = .vertical

view.addSubview(vstack)
vstack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    vstack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
    vstack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    vstack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
])
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple solution - replace the spaces with tabs. No need for monospaced fonts or stack views.

Start with:

```
cell.lbl1.text = "Name\t\t\t- " 
cell.lbl2.text = "Class\t\t\t- " 
cell.lbl3.text = "Reason\t\t\t- "
```

This should line up the hyphens. Depending on the font you might need more or less `\t` (tab) characters in a given label than the others to get it to line up.